# Socket.io in Eventlistener

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, pug

I am trying to send a message whenever user clicks the button with socket.io. Here is my server-side code:

```
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) =>
{
  io.emit("message")
})

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

And here is my frontend js code:

```
var socket = io()

const button = document.querySelector(".yolla")
const form = document.querySelector(".form")
const yazi = document.querySelector(".mesajlar")

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => 
{
  socket.on("message", () => 
  {
    console.log(yazi.value) 
  })
})
```

And here is my pug code:

```
extends ../header2.pug
block unique-css
    include ../../public/css/mentor/chat.css
block unique-content
    .main
        .ekran
            .ust
                h2 Özgür Arslan
                hr
            .msg
            form(action="" class="form")
                input(type="text" class="mesajlar" placeholder="Mesajınızı giriniz.")
                button(class="yolla" type="button") Gönder
    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.1/mustache.min.js")
    script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js")
    script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.6.0/qs.min.js")
    script
        include ../../public/js/mentor
```

When I click the button nothing happens. I want to print the value of input element for all online users in this chat app. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your emit/on functions backwards. The socket.on should happen in the server to react to the socket.emit which should happen in the client (frontend).

```
// Server
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  io.emit('message', 'Welcome'); // To the frontend

  socket.on('message', (msg) => { console.log('Message', msg); }); // From the frontned
});
```

Client:

```
// Frontend
socket.on("message", (msg) => { console.log(msg); }); // From server

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    socket.emit("message", yazi.value); // To server
});
```

Comment: Are you sure? Because when I use it without addEventListener it works fine.

Comment: outside of the event listener, the on would respond to the io.emit from the server, if you are wanting to send the message from the frontend to the server though, you will need to emit from the event listener, and the server should have a socket.on() to receive the message.